# How can I prove this seemingly simple inequality? (Note: I have edited the question)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, modular-arithmetic, linear-transformations, arithmetic

Let $x, y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Define $a,b$ as,

$a=\max$ { $(x)_1, (x)_2, (x)_3,...,(x)_n$}
, $b=\max$ {$(y)_1, (y)_2, (y)_3,...,(y)_n$},
where $(x)_i, (y)_i$ are the $i^{th}$ entry of vectors $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Then how can it be proved that:

$|a-b|\leq \max  \{$|(x-y)_1|,|(x-y)_2|,|(x-y)_3|,...,|(x-y)_n|$\}$.

Comment: This vaguely looks like the triangle inequality for the $\ell^\infty$ norm.

Comment: No, it doesn't look like triangle inequality for $\ell_{\infty}$ norm. Please read carefully.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Can you prove it if $n=2$?  Seems like a natural starting point.

Comment: For $n=2,$  $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(2,0)$ we have $\max(x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2)=0$ and $|a-b|=1.$ Perhaps you wanted $\max\{|x_1-y_1|,\ldots, |x_n-y_n|\}$ on the righ hand side.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc ; Yes, you are right. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is obvious if $a=x_k$ and $b=y_k,$ or $a=b.$
Otherwise the problem reduces to $n=2.$ Indeed assume
$a=x_k$ and $b=y_l,$ $k\neq l.$ We are done if we prove that
$$|x_k-y_l|\le \max\{|x_k-y_k|,|x_l-y_l|\}$$ provided that $x_k> x_l$ and $y_k< y_l.$

Case 1.  $x_k>y_l$

Then
$x_k>y_l>y_k,$ hence $0<x_k-y_l<x_k-y_k.$

Case 2.  $x_k<y_l$

Then $x_l<x_k<y_l$ and $0<y_l-x_k<y_l-x_l.$

Comment: I have found the proof of this inequality, but stack exchange wouldn't allow me to post.